# How do I pass additional data when calling socket.connect() in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to find a way of passing additional data such as username, avatar_url when connecting to socket when user clicks login. Example:

```
const logIn = ({ username, avatar }) => {
   socket.auth = { username };
   socket.connect({ query: { username: username, avatar: avatar } });
}
```

On the server side:

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
    console.log("===> Data:", socket.request._query);
});
```

But I do not get any key-value for username and avatar field. I tried searching the documentation but could not find any information for socket.connect() relating to passing data.

How can I pass data in socket.connect()?

Comment: Just send a message once you get a successful connection.

Comment: I considered that but I want to avoid storing states in the parent component and just send everything to the server in the login method itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use JWT and pass that data as part of the object.

So the flow would be that when you 'auth' have it send back the JWT with the avitar etc.

When you send it to the server and decode the token you can set that as part of the socket object

As an example ( we currently use the jsonwebtoken package )

```
 // verify token
 jwt.verify(token, '[password]', (err, decoded) => {
 try{
 /* connecting */
 
 socket.avitar = decoded.avitar;
 socket.nickname = "nick name";
 if(err) return next(err);
 
 //('success!')
```

Then you can just access it when emitting, because the socket ID is unique to the user it should hold the values, if they disconnect / reconnect the token will still contain the values.

In cluster mode, use redis socket.io and pass this in as an hset to store the data with the socketID